# How often does the prime interest rate change

Tags: canada, interest-rate

How often does the prime interest rate change? Will it only change when the new budget comes out or can it change anytime? I am interested to know this because all other interest rates (i.e mortgage interest rate) are affected by the prime rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the federal funds rate set by the FOMC in the US, the Bank of Canada sets their overnight lending rate 8 times per year.  You can see the [schedule](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/monetary-policy-introduction/key-interest-rate/schedule/) at their website.